# Angular2 Call method in Template

Tags: html, angular, dynamic

How to call a method of a service in the template to create a dynamic table or something else which should be dynamic HTML? I tried with the double curled brackets with `{{anyservice.getDynamicTable(param)}}` but that is not working. What is the way to do this correctly?

Comment: What is a dynamic table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepare the data that you want to display in your controller.

That means you should

1. call the service from your controller,
2. create the datatable,
3. put it in a local variable and then
4. reference this variable from the template.

For example

```
dynamicTable: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dynamicTable = this.anyservice.getDynamicTable();
}
```

or with param

```
createDynamicTable(param) {
   this.dynamicTable = this.anyservice.getDynamicTable(param);
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution for doing it only on purpose? Because if I generate it in the `onInit` I may not have the data there or if I load new data I would have to recall the function.

Comment: I just realised I could call it in the onComplete from my Observable that I receive. That solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

functions defined inside component can be called in template using binding events.

```
<button (click)="methodName()">Label</button>
<select (change)="methodName()"></select>
```

unlike in Angular1 that you needed to use predefined directives like `ng-click` to bind those functions to, in Angular2 you call use this syntax with all the native JavaScript events.

**Edit**
if you have iterations or dynamically generated data:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <button (click)="methodName1(i)">Label</button>
        <button (click)="methodName2(item)">Label</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

as you can see, you can pass numbers, string, booleans or even a whole object.

Comment: This is what i already use for user interaction but now I need to generate a dynamic table only once with the start of my application and I don't know how.

Comment: @moessi774 if you're using this inside component or the properties are defined public, then you get access to then inside component containing this methods. other parameters such as `id`s or `index`es are possible to pass without curly braces

Comment: @moessi774 I added more details

Comment: @moessi774 If you need different methods there instead of passing parameters, you need to use ngIf conditions along with different elements

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that generating the table directly in the template seems to complicated for me. I rather do it in an external function and change this in a later iteration because I am not really sure how to do it exactly.